# Computing a joint distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,N$ be uniform random variables on the unit interval $[0,1]$.

For the interval $[0,2]$ consider a disjoint finite partition $\{Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_M\}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\bigcup_i Z_i =[0,2]\:\:\: \text{and}\: \: Z_i\cap Z_j=\phi, i \neq j
\end{equation}

Define a new random variable $Y=X+N$ and consider the joint event,

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E_{jk}}=\{ X \in Z_j,Y \in Z_k\}
\end{equation}

I am interested in computing $P(\mathcal{E}_{jk})$.

I have the following tried, please correct me if I am wrong.

Suppose $l_j= \lambda(Z_j) $, the length of the interval $ Z_j$, then

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(\mathcal{E_{jk}})&=P(\{ X \in Z_j,Y \in Z_k\}) \\
&= l_jP(Y_i \in Z_k| X \in Z_j) \\
&= l_j \displaystyle \int_{Z_j} f_X(x)P(N \in Z_k-x) \,dx \\
&=l_j l_k
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $Z_k-x:= \{z-x :z \in Z_k\}$

Thank you

Comment: Are you assuming that X and N are independent? Your solution does.

Comment: Yes, thank you.